# git-bash から GitHub にアクセスできない

Tags: windows, git, github, git-bash

Windowsにインストールした git bash で git コマンドを行うと様々な問題が起きます。

`git --version` を使用すれば git インストールの確認はできます。

`git clone` コマンドを使うと以下のようになります。

```
git clone https://～～
Cloning into 'source'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://～～': Failed to connect to PC port 8080: Connection refused
```

リモートリポジトリをセットしようとすると以下のようになります。

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/~~
fatal: No such remote 'origin'
```

何が問題で GitHub と繋げられないかわかりますでしょうか？

Comment: お使いの環境では外部とのネットワークアクセスにプロキシが必要だったりしませんか？

Comment: そんなはずはないのですが、調べてみます。

Comment: 後者の No such remote 'origin' エラーは今回の件とは関係ありません。エラーメッセージの通り、`origin` という名前の remote が存在しないのでエラーになっているだけです。最初は `git remote add` が必要です。前者のエラーを直すのに注目してみてください。

Answer (score 2):

以下を試してみてください。

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/~~
```

２回目から `set-url` が利用可能です。